# What to do if merge, join, and left_join fail?

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to do a "vlookup" in a data.frame without freezing RStudio.

I've tried this

```
hs <- merge(hs_exports, hs_imports)
hs <- left_join(hs_exports, hs_imports)
hs <- join(hs_exports, hs_imports, by = "id")
hs <- sqldf("select * from hs_exports left join hs_imports using (id)")
```

`hs_exports` uses 590 MB in RAM and `hs_imports` uses 640 MB in RAM. I have more than 4GB of free RAM.

This is the structure of my files:

`hs_exports`: 3 columns

1. year
2. id
3. export_value

`hs_imports`: 3 columns

1. year
2. id
3. import_value

I just need to combine both things to have a data.frame with 4 columns:

1. year
2. id
3. export_value
4. import_value

A so-called reproducible example would be this

```
library(plyr)

df1 <- mtcars
df1$car_name <- rownames(df1)
df1 <- df1[,c("car_name","mpg","cyl")]

df2 <- mtcars
df2$car_name <- rownames(df2)
df2 <- df2[,c("car_name","disp")]

df3 <- join(df1, df2, by = "car_name")
```

But the things is how to find something equivalent to the last line that does not freeze RStudio.

Comment: Maybe a `data.table` join? Something like `setDT(df1); setDT(df2); df1[df2, on=c("year", "id")]` should work if both data sets have the same year-ids. Otherwise, this is known as a left-join.

Comment: I didn't think about that and I went straight into sql arguments ! I'm gonna try